# How can I solve the matplotlib colormap error: ValueError?

Tags: python, matplotlib, valueerror, colormap

my value

```
t = np.array(range(0, 10))
y = np.array([9, 8, 7, 9, 8, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4])
```

my colormap details

```
colormap = t

def DrawGraph():

    plt.figure(figsize=(20,6))
    plt.plot(t, y, s=50, c=colormap, marker=">")
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()

DrawGraph()
```

and here is the problem
: ValueError: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) is not a valid value for color

Why does this error appear? How can I solve this?

I was wondering if it was a problem that the values of the variables were different, so I looked at the variables and they are all the same length.

I'm so curious where the problem came from if the length is not the problem.

Comment: `plt.plot()` doesn't work with a colormap. It normally draws a connected curve, for which you can specify one color.  You can use `plt.scatter()` to work with individually marked points, which all can have different colors.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @[JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12046409/johanc) in the comments, the `plt.plot` function only allows you to set a single color for all the points. That said, the `plt.scatter` function does allow you to set different colors for each of the points.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.array(range(0, 10))
y = np.array([9, 8, 7, 9, 8, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4])

plt.figure(figsize=(20,6))
plt.scatter(t, y, s=50, c=t, marker=">")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]